# Sufficient statistics and isometries

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry, information-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be an infinite dimensional statistical manifold with the Fisher information metric $g$. Is it true that any isometry on this manifold must correspond to a sufficient statistic?

Comment: didn't it occur to you to post this on maths overflow? (though unlikely to be answered there)